# Can Tkinter keypress modules be used when in CLI

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, keypress

Let's say I need to make use of keypress events. The easiest solution I have so far is the Tkinter module (testing for cross platforms after the code is done).

However, I suck at programming GUI so I am starting with a CLI first. Am I able to use Tkinter.bind() in CLI mode?

I am on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not able to use Tkinter's `bind` method for a CLI program.